# Upgrade to ruby 2.0.0-p247 and rails 4.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

I want to upgrade 2 apps to **ruby 2.0.0-p247** and **rails 4.0.0**.

Upgrading from:
**ruby 1.9.3**
**rails 3.2.13**
I use RVM to manage rubies and gems.

What I'm gonna do.

**I. Upgrade ruby**
In terminal (from any dir):

1. `$ rvm install 2.0.0`
2. `$ rvm --default use 2.0.0`
3. `$ rvm gemset copy 1.9.3-p392@myBlog 2.0.0-p247@myBlog`

Do I need to do something else to update ruby for my apps? Or it's enough to finish the update?
P.S. I don't have `.ruby-version` file in app root directory.

**II. Upgrade rails**
I'm gonna follow this cast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/415-upgrading-to-rails-4
Any additional comments for these steps?

**III. Deploy to production**
I'll change the ruby version for my projects via CP of my hosting.
And... `cap deploy`

Did I miss something?

Comment: Good luck with your upgrade. IMO, your question as it stands isn't a good fit for this site. I suggest you dive in on what you've described and post back here **specific questions** related to problems that come up along the way.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Will do. I'm 4-month-old ruby programmer, so before the upgrade I want to make sure, that I didn't miss some big thing of upgrade process.

Comment: Yeah. You've missed running your test suite.

Comment: Check out [ready4rails4](http://ready4rails4.net/) for a list of gems & their compatibility with Rails 4.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if your gems are compatible with Ruby2 and Rails 4;
2. Make sure that your test suite is green;
3. Make sure that your test suite is testing everything that can break with this upgrade;
4. Make some manual tests for something that you missed during the automated tests and make sure that you'll automate it later;
5. Depending on apps size, put them in some test area before change the production application;

Comment: One question on this: How do you check if your gem is compatible with a specific Ruby version?